# Change php.ini settings without modifying the original php.ini file or using the htaccess

Tags: apache, php

The default php.ini value on my server for file uploading(upload_max_filesize, post_max_size) is 10M. I wanted to increase it to 40M. How do I do that?

Method 1: I can't use. This method doesn't work in this specific case.

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "40M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "40M");
```

Method 2: I can't do it using the htaccess either. Because when I do so my server changes my .htaccess file with the following error

```
# For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
```

Method 3: And I don't want to make changes to the default php.ini file because that will change the settings throughout the whole server.

Method 4: I have heard that I can create a php.ini file in my site and define the settings there but it didn't work either. My code for that file. (I kind of have a feeling that I applied this method in a wrong way)

```
[PHP]

upload_max_filesize =40M
post_max_size =40M
```

Comment: You might be able to get those variables set in VirtualHost block in Apache... Or you can consider changing your hosting provider.

Comment: PHP's file uploads are handled/processed in full BEFORE the associated .php script is executed. As such, you MUST have the options in place at the .ini and/or .htaccess level. If your hosting provider does not allow these changes, then you're SOL and can't use PHP to handle your upload. As you say in your method #1 - that doesn't work. ini_set() calls won't be processed until after the upload has completed (and/or failed).

Comment: @abhig Just out of interest, why is 10 meg not enough?

Comment: @Pete Well my client needs to upload files upto 40MB's.

Comment: @abhig OK - I deserved that answer :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to use custom php.ini files and link them to .htaccess file? That might work for me.

Comment: TBH I think you might need to talk to the server admin. In theory, it shouldn't really be a problem because there'll be a disk quota that prevents your client filling the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, method 4 worked for me as I thought. I just had to do it the right way. Adding this specific line to my .htaccess file reads the newly created php.ini file in that folder.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Answer (score 0):

On Bluehost cpanel PHP Configuration I selected PHP 5.2
"All files with the extension .php will be handled by the PHP 5.2 engine.
Legacy PHP with security updates. Compatible with most environments. "

To eliminate the "#For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini..." message.